# SQLAlchemy distinct() doesn't return unique records with a keyword search

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a search bar which searches for users with the following query:

```
db.session.query(User).filter(or_(User.name.contains(keyword), User.location.contains(keyword))).limit(16).all()
```

As you can see, it searches using keywords (which comes from a list formed by the search query). If I search for 'John Smith', the search will find a user with a name containing 'John' and then the same user with a name containing 'Smith', so it will return the User twice.

To solve this issue I tried using `distinct()` like so:

```
db.session.query(User).distinct().filter(or_(User.name.contains(keyword), User.location.contains(keyword))).limit(16).all()
```

but it didn't work so I tried using `distinct(User.id)`:

```
db.session.query(User).distinct(User.id).filter(or_(User.name.contains(keyword), User.location.contains(keyword))).limit(16).all()
```

though that did not work either.
So what is the problem?

**Edit:**

One bit I forgot to mention the code looks like this:

```
query = 'John Smith'
for keyword in query.split():
    db.session.query(User).distinct().filter(or_(User.name.contains(keyword), User.location.contains(keyword))).limit(16).all()
```

This is why it returns 2 of the same user. I use the for loop because there are other field to the database, so if I searched for `John Smith Mexico` it would search by each word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is having one unique query for all the keywords that you would like to search for. (That is, instead of the `distinct`, which does not know that you are actually running queries in a loop; the `distinct` will be applied independently to each of the queries, and that's why you get 2 results).

Something like this would work:

```
In [17]:

from sqlalchemy import or_
query = 'John Smith'
keyword_c = [User.name.contains(keyword) for keyword in query] + [User.location.contains(keyword) for keyword in query]
q = session.query(User).filter(or_(*keyword_c))
for x in q.limit(16).all():
    print x.name

John Smith
```

Hope it helps.