# SQLAlchemy query for array containing any one of multiple values

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I figured I could find answer to this on the internet somewhere, but I seem to have missed it.
You can query a table for all rows where an array column contains a specific value:

```
MyModel.query.filter(Mymodel.arrayField.contains(['someValue'])
```

And you can put in multiple values such that the array must contain **all** the specified values:

```
MyModel.query.filter(Mymodel.arrayField.contains(['someValue', 'anotherValue'])
```

But what about querying and where the array contains **at-least one** of the specified values.  That is, a query that would return rows where `arrayField` contains `'someValue'` or `'anotherValue'`, and maybe both but not necessarily both.

How would I do that?

Comment: Please take a look to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334704/sqlalchemy-distinct-doesnt-return-unique-records-with-a-keyword-search/32359134#32359134)

Answer (score 7):

The Postgresql concept here is [overlapping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html) arrays, implemented using the `&&` operator:

```
test# SELECT ARRAY['a', 'x'] && ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'] AS overlaps;
 overlaps 
══════════
 t
(1 row)

test# SELECT ARRAY['q', 'x'] && ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'] AS overlaps;
 overlaps 
══════════
 f
(1 row)
```

SQLAlchemy provides an [overlap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY.Comparator.overlap) method on the [ARRAY](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY) type in the Postgresql dialect that implements `&&`.

An ORM query checking for columns containing at least one of `'a'` and `'z'` would look like

```py
session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.array_field.overlap(['a', 'z']))
```

or SQLAlchemy 2.0-style:

```py
select(MyModel).where(MyModel.array_field.overlap(['a', 'z']))
```

or if you prefer to be closer to the Postgres syntax:

```py
select(MyModel).where(MyModel.array_field.op('&&')(['a', 'z']))
```