# Filter postgres STRING ARRAY Column with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to filter a query result by a ARRAY of STRINGS Column, on Postgres database. And need it to be case insensitive, working as '***ilike***' postgres function.
Here is the query that I need to work in FLask-SQLAlchemy syntax:

```
select * from articles a 
where array_to_string(a.tags, ',') ilike any (array['%football%', '%basketball%'])
```

I've already tried these syntaxes:

```
Article.query.filter(Article.tags.contains(f"{{{tags}}}")).all()
Article.query.filter(Article.tags.ilike(f"%{tags}%")).all()
Article.query.filter(Article.tags.in_(tags).all()
```

Where tags is a list of strings like this:

```
tags = [
            'football', 
            'basketball', 
            'hockey', 
            'soccer', 
            'baseball', 
            'golf', 
            'fighting', 
            'tennis'
        ]
```

SQLAlchemy model definition:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'

    article_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    headline = db.Column(db.String)
    source = db.Column(db.String)
    summary = db.Column(db.String)
    tags = db.Column(ARRAY(db.String), default=[])
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    url = db.Column(db.String)
    .
    .
    .
```

I've already checked the documentation and another similar questions, and didn't find any solution that fits my needs.

Comment: I think you can use `overlap` in that case, check an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747623/sqlalchemy-query-for-array-containing-any-one-of-multiple-values

Comment: Works if I have a single word in each item of that tag column, sometimes I have like "Euro Football" and I just want to filter by "football", case insensitive, and need it to find the word inside a bigger string as: ilike ('%football%')

Comment: now I understand in that case maybe you can use `column_property` in your model and create a fake column from your array `tags` in your model to create the string from the array and then compare with `contains`, I will try to create the scenario but I need to prepare my environment. Check here to see what I'm talking about https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html

Answer (score 1):

To make like the query that are you talking about you can use the functions `array_to_string` and `_any` from SQLAlchemy functions for example like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
```

```
articles = Article.query.filter(
    func.array_to_string(Article.tags, ','). \
        ilike(func.any_(['%fighting%', '%golf%']))
    ).all()
```

Inside the `any_` function you can pass down your array to make the search.

See `any_` documentation [sqlalchemy any_ column modifier](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.any_).